# Why I'm not able to make a keyed stream out of this

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I've been trying different methods but unable to get right. what's wrong in this code?

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD: Double = 50.00

    val see: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")

    val src  = see.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010("broadcast",
      new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(true), properties))

    src.map {
      v =>
        val key = v.get("locationID").asText
        val temperature = v.get("temp").asDouble()
        (key, temperature)
    }
        .keyBy(v => v._2)


    src.print()
    see.execute()

    case class Event(locationID: String, temp: Double)
```

I want an alert when the flink reads the value above threshold

```
[{"locationID": "ASK","temp": 35},
{"locationID": "BC","temp": 45},
{"locationID":"CHD","temp": 55},
{"locationID": "RAJ","temp": 65},
{"locationID": "EGY","temp": 55}]
```

Error I'm getting is:

> Job Execution Failed

Comment: that error description is... ... ... ... short.

Comment: Kindly refer to this ,It would be really helpful for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233895/unable-to-make-keyed-stream