# I'm getting unexpected error in JSON file

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

While consuming JSON file from Kafka in flink I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"[{"; line: 1, column: 2])
>            at [Source: (byte[])"[{"; line: 1, column: 5]

This is my JSON File:

```
[{
        "locationID": "ASK",
        "temp": 35
    },
    {
        "locationID": "BC",
        "temp": 45
    },
    {
        "locationID":"CHD",
        "temp": 55
    },
    {
        "locationID": "RAJ",
        "temp": 65
    },
    {
        "locationID": "EGY",
        "temp": 55
}]
```

This is the code :

[Why I'm not able to make a keyed stream out of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220391/why-im-not-able-to-make-a-keyed-stream-out-of-this)

Comment: Does your call work with all the line breaks removed?

Comment: Lemme check, kind of you to help

Comment: ```Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Array (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"[{"locationID": "ASK","temp": 35}"; line: 1, column: 1])
 at [Source: (byte[])"[{"locationID": "ASK","temp": 35}"; line: 1, column: 67] ```  This is the new error

Comment: Probably a good idea if you posted whatever commands you're running or any supporting code that executes this call.

Comment: I'll do that for sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to make keyed stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58233895/unable-to-make-keyed-stream)

Comment: Yes @JeffreyChung I apologise for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you always need to input one-line json strings. So in your example use this:

`[{"locationID": "ASK", "temp": 35}, {"locationID": "BC", "temp": 45}, {"locationID": "CHD", "temp": 55}, {"locationID": "RAJ", "temp": 65}, {"locationID": "EGY", "temp": 55}]`

For a more generic approach you may use something like the following to reformat your  multiline json strings:

`.selectExpr("REPLACE(CAST(value as string), '\n', '') as json")`

Comment: I guess there's an error in the code itself, Thanks alot for the help

Comment: Where to add this depends on your actual code. Generally you would use this on a DataFrame. Further reading over here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#selectExpr(scala.collection.Seq)

Comment: I'm using flink here (you can refer to the link in the error), 
Thank you