# How to omit a null value exception in flink-kafka , Any help would do

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink

I'm trying to make a code that creates alert when temperature is above threshold temperature (as defined in the  code), but keyed stream is creating problem. I'm new to flink and intermediate in scala. I need help in this code

I've tried almost everything

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val TEMPERATURE_THRESHOLD: Double = 50.00

    val see: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")

    val src = see.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010("broadcast",
      new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(true), properties))


    var data = src.map { v => {
      val loc = v.get("locationID").asInstanceOf[String]
      val temperature = v.get("temp").asDouble()
    //val json = Map("locationID" -> locationID, "temp" -> v.temp)
    //val jsonVal = JSONObject(json).toString()
      (loc, temperature)
    }}
 data = data
      .keyBy(
        v => v._1
      )
```

```
{"locationID": "ASK", "temp": 35} {"locationID": "BC", "temp": 45} {"locationID": "CHD", "temp": 55} {"locationID": "RAJ", "temp": 65} {"locationID": "EGY", "temp": 55}
```

I think my tuple is taking null value from somewhere , I need help omit that error

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
...

    at flinkBroadcast1$.main(flinkBroadcast1.scala:59)
    at flinkBroadcast1.main(flinkBroadcast1.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
...
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: There is invalid json somewhere in your payload (actually line 1 column 21). Something like `{"key": locationID`. `locationID[` is not valid json. The parser was expecting `true`, `false`, or `null`. Can you include the json payload?

Comment: ```
[{"locationID": "ASK", "temp": 35}, {"locationID": "BC", "temp": 45}, {"locationID": "CHD", "temp": 55}, {"locationID": "RAJ", "temp": 65}, {"locationID": "EGY", "temp": 55}]
```
Thanks for the help , here is the JSON payload (it's just an example)

Comment: Ok, but not only any example. Does that json you post raise the error? In any case, the expected values by the parser do not make much sense for the code you post (`true`, `false`, `null`), neither is a string value. So you may need to look at that.

Comment: I looked into that and fixed the problem by registering the schema but this issue still exists (error)

Comment: I suggest you give a proper look into the issue. Every time I get back, your question is different. Now you're having a `NulPointerException`, I have no idea where that is coming, you do not provide enough detail to answer that question. From my perspective, your initial question was answered by @fabianhueske, and your second question by me with my first comment. As for your 3rd question, I will say it has nothing to do with the title of your question.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Okay, Let me edit everything so that it's clear as crystal, I'm sorry for not being able to come up clearly but check it now, I think it's gonna help you find the error that I'm unable to detect . Check th question now